# How can i use syntax-highlighting without blinking in C# Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I have a RichTextBox, what is calling a function at case of "TextChanged" event. I found a code on the internet, but when i'm editing the text, it's blinking. (the code have some lines to prevent it). What is the standard to do it right?

i tried this code: http://www.codingvision.net/interface/c-simple-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Did you include line 40 `titleLabel.Focus();`? It seems it solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, i used the whole code.

Comment: Well, @Alex , it seems that if enough characters are loaded into the `RichTextBox`, the text begins to flicker because it is re-coloring every word.. Any solutions?

Comment: @Momoro, try to locate just the piece you change and re-color only that part. Looks like a non-trivial task, but still possible. For example, to locate changes you can use information on the cursor position and compare the text before and after editing.

Comment: @Alex I think I understand, but the code from the link provided by the OP is **hard** to re-code, seeing as it is in `Regex`

Comment: @Momoro, yes, the code by the link has its shortcomings (e.g., one has to provide all classes names, the code also can not handle context-dependent key words like `select`) and could be improved. I guess it's just a proof of concept. Moreover `Regex` isn't the best way for syntactic analysis. For that purpose one should use tokenization and syntactic trees. Luckily there is a standard tool. Take a look at the [.NET Compiler Platform SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/).

Comment: Ahh, thanks, @Alex :)